# Using ECDSA for signing api requests

Tags: api, authentication, ecdsa

Is it a good choice to use ECDSA for signing API requests, given the following conditions:

1. Only clients must be able to create signatures
2. Requests integrity must be verifiable, eg. we should know if a replay-attack was initiated
3. If the keys database would be compromised, the client keys should still be valid.

Signature is made from the request endpoint + params + timestamp. Hashed and signed.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Also i found one example of such auth https://docs.silamoney.com/docs/process-overview